# Strongloop: setup Storage Component for Amazon S3

Tags: node.js, amazon-s3, strongloop, loopbackjs

I'm new to Node.js and Loopback. I have been using Deployd so far and I'm trying to migrate to Loopback. The S3 bucket module on Deployd was working great.

So...:

I'm on this website https://github.com/strongloop/loopback-component-storage

I run, in my project folder,

```
npm install loopback-component-storage
```

I then need to create a datasource. 
To setup the new datasource, I tried

```
slc loopback:datasource
```

It doesn't provide me with the option to create a source that is a storage. So I rule that option out I guess

I see there is this piece of code on the github (link above):

```
var ds = loopback.createDataSource({
    connector: require('loopback-component-storage'),
    provider: 'filesystem',
    root: path.join(__dirname, 'storage')
});

var container = ds.createModel('container');

app.model(container);
```

I guess this is the right way to create a datasource, but where do I place this code and how do I execute it?
How do I adapt this code to work with Amazon?

```
{ provider: 'amazon', key: '...', keyId: '...' }
```

I suppose `key` is my secret key and `keyId` my access key id, but can you confirm?

I'm just having trouble getting started... thanks for your help in advance

Comment: @RaymondFeng : They need to update the docs for loopback-component-storage to use it in loopback 2.0. And they must properly document how to integrate loopback-component-storage into an existing project.

Comment: It's on our plate to upgrade the example to work with LoopBack 2.x.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a datasource manually in server/datasources.json too. This way, you should be able to create a container model using the storage data source.

To do this by code as you illustrated, you can either modify server/server.js or drop a JS file into server/boot with an exported function as:

```
module.exports = function(app) {
  // your code
};
```

Comment: I tried that (adding to datasources.json) but it wouldn't work... can you please provide code for example? Thanks

Comment: I just created a working example at https://github.com/strongloop/loopback-component-storage/tree/master/example-2.0. Check it out, run npm install; node . and open browser to http://localhost:3000

Comment: in your example, can you add an amazon datasource in your datasources.json?

Answer (score 2):

1. Where to put the code: https://github.com/strongloop/loopback-component-storage/blob/master/example/app.js

   - tl;dr, just put it in `app.js` (1.x structure) or `server/server.js` (2.x structure)
   - This example I linked to is using the old LoopBack 1.x structure. I will be updating that example in the coming weeks to use the new LoopBack 2.x structure.
2. Amazon provider example: http://docs.strongloop.com/display/LB/Storage+service

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @Raymond, I took the second option.
I created file *server/boot/xyz.js* and put this in there:

```
module.exports = function(server) {
    var path = require('path');
    var ds = server.loopback.createDataSource({
        connector: require('loopback-component-storage'),
        provider: 'filesystem',
        root: path.join(__dirname, '../../storage')
    });
    var container = ds.createModel('container');
    server.model(container);
};
```

I cannot see the model in the explorer but I can call the service with:

```
http://localhost:3000/api/containers
```

Comment: @Raymond: How to make the service appear in explorer? Is it supported? I think the end state is that all the modules should be integrated together for easier understanding and setup. I really like the command line setup -- very convenient, less risky